# Firebase.jobdispatcher with RxJava2 doesn't work asynchronously

Tags: android, firebase, rx-java2, firebase-job-dispatcher

I am trying to start Firebase jobdispatcher asynchronously using RxJava2.

```
@Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
    Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
            @Override
            public void run() throws Exception {
                startMethod();
            }
        }).subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
          .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.mainThread())
          .subscribeWith(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                LOG.debug("onComplete");
                onStopJob(job);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }
        });
        return true;
}

@Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
        LOG.debug("stop job");
        return true;
}
```

When i added `subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())` line the `startMethod()` doesn't start, if I delete this line the `startMethod()` starts in Main thread.

Comment: 1. What are the mSchedulerProvider.io()` and `mSchedulerProvider.mainThread()`. Why not use `Schedulers.io()` and `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` .
2. Is it a must to use RxJava

Comment: 1) It's the same. 2) What do you suggestion to use. I am using RxJava in project that is why i try to use it in this place.

Comment: If I am correct, you want to know when the execution of the `startMethod()` on a different thread is complete? So you can call` onStopJob()`?

Comment: Can I also get a code snippet of the `startMethod()`

Comment: No. If I start with mSchedulerProvider.io() nothing work, I can't understand why dispatcher won't work with Schedulers.io().

Comment: startMethod  is a big  method, but i can do it empty it doesn't depend because the startMethod doesn't start at all.

Comment: Please see if there is an `onError` callback and `printStackTrace` it.

Comment: I can't understand the problem because even an empty method works unstably, it works, then it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem may be in the `observeOn` statement. I tried replicating the code you have. But since I assume you are not trying to update the UI thread, removing the `observeOn` will allow the process to finish on the `RxCachedScheduler` thread that the `Schedulers.io()` creates and will not block the UI

```
Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            Log.e("RXJAVA","Running on | " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            startMethod();
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   // .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) //Try comment this out
    //also try subscribe instead of subscribeWith
    .subscribe(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            System.err.println("RXJAVA onComplete | " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Log.e("RXJAVA","onComplete | " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: This did not solve the problem. Even with an empty method it works unstably

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem could potentially be from RxJava itself Try replacing your code with this. I would advise just use a simple Java threading primitive e.g. `ExecutorService` or `CompletableFuture`. Here's an example

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
            .execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startMethod();
                    onJobFinished(job); //job may need to be final;
                }
            });
```

If the following doesn't work, confirm that your Service is actually being called. Check your manifest that you have declared your service there. etc

Comment: Thank you for your sample. I changed the app using IntentService and all works perfect. I agree that the problem in RxJava. But a lot of people using RxJava and it's necessary to understand why there is a problem. I added this question to firebase github.

Comment: Maybe do you know how to stop JobService from IntentService correctly?

Comment: Hey Delphian, glad to have helped a bit. Not so sure how to stop JobService. I have used RxJava and sometimes I do get unexpected Behavior especially when I try using Threading. My rule of Thumb is if it involves Threading, I just use Plain Java Threading methods